# Prevent newline rule to apply on header np.savetxt

Tags: python, string, numpy, text

I've got a .csv file which I wanna save as .txt
Here's my original data:
[Org-data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVOrz.png)

I save this file as .txt with the following rules for newlines, coments, etc:

```
np.savetxt(r'/test/text.txt', df, newline=',\n', comments='',fmt='%f', header=''.join(f'{col}\t' for col in df.columns)[:-1])
```

[Result-textfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ez9d.jpg)

**The problem is that I need all lines to have "," and the end of them except for the first line**
But in this situation, the newline rule which I specified in the code above applies to all the lines!

Know any way to prevent this to happen?

Or do you know another way to create the desired text file?

**Example:**

Consider this as the original data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'NumberOfPages:float': {0: 96.0, 1: 96.0, 2: 144.0},
 'bid:token': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 5}})
```

the output should look like this:

```
bid:token   NumberOfPages:float
3.000000 96.000000,
3.000000 96.000000,
5.000000 144.000000,
```

But I get this:

```
bid:token   NumberOfPages:float,
3.000000 96.000000,
3.000000 96.000000,
5.000000 144.000000,
```

***Note the "," symbol after float in the first line.**

Comment: Can you add a small executable example that shows your problem? This most importantly includes some data (e.g. initialize some dataframe or `np.array`) and (less importantly) the expected output in text form.  If you add actual code instead of screenshots, you'll have a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: @André Hi, thanks for your comment, but actually it's not a data-related problem. It's about make an exception while a rule is being applied to a text tile.

Comment: @André I added an example. Does it help?

Comment: Now some lines of code that set the corresponding input `df` and we've got the minimal reproducible example :-)

Comment: @André Fixed it! Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the character afterwards

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'NumberOfPages:float': {0: 96.0, 1: 96.0, 2: 144.0},
 'bid:token': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 5}})

np.savetxt('test.txt', df, newline=',\n', comments='',fmt='%f', header=''.join(f'{col}\t' for col in df.columns)[:-1])

with open("test.txt", 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines[0] = lines[0].replace(',', '') # Only modify header
    f.seek(0)
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Output:

```
NumberOfPages:float bid:token
96.000000 3.000000,
96.000000 3.000000,
144.000000 5.000000,
```

Note that this could be slow for very large files, since `f.readlines()` should read all lines of the file. If it is possible to overwrite the comma with a space, you can also use this, which does not load the complete file into memory:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'NumberOfPages:float': {0: 96.0, 1: 96.0, 2: 144.0},
 'bid:token': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 5}})

np.savetxt('test.txt', df, newline=',\n', comments='',fmt='%f', header=''.join(f'{col}\t' for col in df.columns)[:-1])

with open("test.txt", 'r+') as f:
    header = f.readline()
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(f"{header[:-2]} ")
```

Output:

```
NumberOfPages:float bid:token <--- beware this space
96.000000 3.000000,
96.000000 3.000000,
144.000000 5.000000,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but actually I was looking for a way to edit the file BEFORE saving it cause as you also mentioned, this solution is computationally expensive for large files (my files are pretty large). 
Do you know a better solution?

Comment: The second solution only reads the first line.

Comment: Yea the second solution is better. but as I mentioned, I wanna do all the editions BEFORE saving them. I don't wanna load them twice

Comment: Is there a problem with it? Why do you not want to touch the file?

Comment: cause It's not acceptable to consume a lot of memory to delete a single character.

Comment: So it does open the whole file in the **second** solution that I've posted? Honestly, you've got to tell me what's wrong with it, in my answer I've clearly stated that I believe the second solution does **not** read the full file. If you find that is not true and don't tell me you can't expect me to know. So, why do you believe the second solution reads the whole file?